# Option 'getWithBody' of HttpComponent is not working in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

The version of Apache Camel is 2.18.1

In documentation for 2.x, https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http4-component.html, **getWithBody** and **deleteWithBody** options as query parameters are provided.

> - deleteWithBody (producer) : Whether the HTTP DELETE should include the message body or not. By default HTTP DELETE do not include any HTTP body. However in some rare cases users may need to be able to include the message body. Default: false
> - getWithBody (producer) : Whether the HTTP GET should include the message body or not. By default HTTP GET do not include any HTTP body. However in some rare cases users may need to be able to include the message body. Default false

But when I concatenate one of these 2 parameters at the end of the endpoint URI, it's not recognized as an option. Instead, it's passed to the endpoint as an ordinary query parameter, while other query parameter options are treated as component options and not forwarded to the endpoint.

When I inspect the source code, I see that options are recognized by matching with the fields and methods of **HttpEndpoint** *(org.apache.camel.component.http4)* and **HttpCommonEndpoint** *(org.apache.camel.http.common)* classes. **getWithBody** and **deleteWithBody** fields doesn't exist in these classes while other options can be found among the fields of these classes.

Can I assume that the documentation is wrong? If so, how can I achieve to send body with HttpComponent(Http4Component) of Camel while the http method is GET or DELETE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `deleteWithBody` was introduced in Apache Camel 2.19.0. See [CAMEL-10916](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10916).

Option `getWithBody` was introduced in Apache Camel 3.0.0 and backported to 2.25.0. See [CAMEL-14118](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14118).

For such old version use docs archived on github, it is not published on website - https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.18.x/components/camel-http4/src/main/docs/http4-component.adoc

You need to update to newer version or implement custom component overriding some methods from HTTP4 component. There is no option to enable this OOTB in 2.18.1.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with the answer given by @Bedla.

to add something additional this is what we did .

We checked the code and debugged - this allowed us to realize that at a point were camel interacts it drops the body if a GET Call has a one. it will be send as a normal GET Request because Camel version 3.x.x only supports it.

we tried different ways to forcefully add the body. that was also failed because what ever we add will be discarded by camel.

we were using camel v2.22.1 at the time. going to a higher version such as camel 3.x.x will be a big leap since there are multiple changes that will be included , so lucky for us camel team back ported this ability to send the GET Request with the Body (from here on getWithBody) to camel v2.25.0

coding level changes :
Append `getWithBody=true` to the Request URL

**Updated camel Modules**

```
camel-core-2.25.0.jar
camel-cxf-transport-2.25.0.jar
camel-cxf-2.25.0.jar
camel-core-xml-2.25.0.jar
camel-http-common-2.25.0.jar
camel-jaxb-2.25.0.jar
camel-spring-2.25.0.jar
camel-soap-2.25.0.jar
camel-cdi-2.25.0.jar
camel-jdbc-2.25.0.jar
camel-http4-2.25.0.jar
```

****special note ****
Note that under each folder location, there is a modules.xml file. You need yo open that and change the jar file version number to the one you want to use. in this case 2.25.0

That’s it and Happy Coding !